# What's a closed countably infinite intersection?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

When operating with sigma algebras, what does it mean when we talk about a countably infinite set? And, what are then closed countably infinite interesections?

Comment: A set which is countably infinite.  I don't follow.  As for the second question, you should quote whatever it is you're having trouble following in full.

Comment: These definitions would be near the front of any textbook on measure theory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I expect that you have read that a sigma algebra $\mathcal{A}$ has
to be "closed under countably infinite intersections". What this means
is that if you have a family $(A_n)$ of elements of $\mathcal{A}$
indexed by the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$, then the intersection
$\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n$ of all the $A_n$ is also an element of $\mathcal{A}$.